# Android Bumblebee Gradle Error - Unable to load class 'com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension' (HILT)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-bumblebee

After update android studio to bumblebee, my gradle crash

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/api/extension/AndroidComponentsExtension
at dagger.hilt.android.plugin.HiltGradlePlugin.configureBytecodeTransformASM(HiltGradlePlugin.kt:257)
at dagger.hilt.android.plugin.HiltGradlePlugin.configureHilt(HiltGradlePlugin.kt:89)
at dagger.hilt.android.plugin.HiltGradlePlugin.access$configureHilt(HiltGradlePlugin.kt:59)
at dagger.hilt.android.plugin.HiltGradlePlugin$apply$1.execute(HiltGradlePlugin.kt:66)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.